# How to add header properties in kafka message while sending message to producer using C#?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

```
                var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
                var client = new KafkaNet.Producer(router, maximumAsyncRequests, maximumMessageBuffer);
                var text="";
                    var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:/kafka_examples/consumed_files123.ifc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                     Console.WriteLine(text);
                    client.SendMessageAsync("Hello-Kafka", new[]
                  { new Message(text) }).Wait();

                }
```

This is the code I used to send my message to the producer which is working fine but now I wanna add some header properties with the message. Please help me now to add header properties using C#.

Answer (score 2):

Simple headers example using ConfluentKafka:

```
Headers hd = new Headers()
{
    new Header("test-key-1", new byte[100]),
    new Header("test-key-2", new byte[101])
};
            

var msg = new Message<int, YourValueObject>()
{
    Key = yourKey,
    Value = yourValue,
    Headers = hd
};

....
await _producer.ProduceAsync("topic", msg);
```

Comment: is it possible to have header values as String?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was on vacation.  You can get the bytes from the string
header.Add(“key”, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(“value”)) ;